# Ubuntu 14.04.1 encrypt home directory

Tags: encryption

I am trying to encrypt the home directory of a user. I have found this [guide on howtogeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/116032/how-to-encrypt-your-home-folder-after-installing-ubuntu/).

I have then tested the guide on a virtual machine with a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04.1 (which had all the updates installed before beginning) and it went exactly as described in the tutorial.

Now I come to try and replicate this on my users system.

```
$ sudo apt-get install ecryptfs-utils cryptsetup
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
cryptsetup is already the newest version.
ecryptfs-utils is already the newest version.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.

$ sudo ecryptfs-migrate-home -u <username>
INFO:  Checking disk space, this may take a few moments.  Please be patient.
INFO:  Checking for open files in /home/<username>
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/112/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
Enter your login passphrase [<username>]: 

************************************************************************
YOU SHOULD RECORD YOUR MOUNT PASSPHRASE AND STORE IT IN A SAFE LOCATION.
  ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase ~/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
THIS WILL BE REQUIRED IF YOU NEED TO RECOVER YOUR DATA AT A LATER TIME.
************************************************************************

Done configuring.

chown: cannot access ‘/dev/shm/.ecryptfs-<username>’: No such file or directory
mount: No such file or directory
ERROR:  Could not mount
```

When I inspect the path that it's complaining about it look strange, but a little googling indictates this is to be expected of fuse.

```
$ sudo ls -lash /run/user/112/
ls: cannot access /run/user/112/gvfs: Permission denied
total 0
0 drwx------ 6 lightdm lightdm 140 Oct 31 11:06 .
0 drwxr-xr-x 4 root    root     80 Oct 31 11:05 ..
0 drwx------ 2 lightdm lightdm  60 Oct 31 11:05 dconf
? d????????? ? ?       ?         ?            ? gvfs
0 drwx------ 2 lightdm lightdm  80 Oct 31 11:04 pulse
0 drwx------ 3 lightdm lightdm  60 Oct 31 11:04 upstart
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root    root     17 Oct 31 11:04 X11-display -> /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
```

And the file it's complaining about not being able to find really doesn't appear to be there.

```
$ sudo ls -lash /dev/shm/.ecryptfs-<username>
ls: cannot access /dev/shm/.ecryptfs-rob: No such file or directory
$ sudo ls -lash /dev/shm/
total 144K
   0 drwxrwxrwt  2 root    root    100 Oct 31 11:04 . 
   0 drwxr-xr-x 24 root    root    800 Oct 31 11:05 ..
 68K -rwx------  1 lightdm lightdm 65M Oct 31 11:04 pulse-shm-1911916644
 72K -rwx------  1 lightdm lightdm 65M Oct 31 11:04 pulse-shm-1958822985
4.0K -rwx------  1 lightdm lightdm 65M Oct 31 11:04 pulse-shm-2556483462
```

And I am no longer able to continue.

Comment: Did you try doing the process while logged out (i.e. from a VTT like you get with Ctrl+Alt+F1)?

Comment: Sort off. I am not logged in on the desktop at all. Actually I am doing this over an ssh session, I'm about to go and try it on a local login rather than a remote one.

When I did the encryption on the virtual machine test I was able to do it from a graphical login, but as a different user (you can't encrypt your own home directory).

Comment: I am trying from a local logon now rather than from an SSH session and it appears to have gotten further - will report back once It's finished whether that solved it - but looks like you can't do this operation over SSH.

Comment: Well, I was more curious as to whether you were logged into the account you were trying to encrypt. But, hope it goes well

Comment: Yeah it was very clear in the guide I linked at the top that you have to perform this operation as a different user account than the one you are trying to encrypt.

Answer (score 2):

I used a desktop session of a second user and it worked flawlessly,it would appear it's not possible over SSH.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to log in as **another** user than the one you want to encrypt via **SSH** or locally. I temporarily logged in *directly* as `root` instead of my sudoer user.

Note: Logging in as the user you want to encrypt the `$HOME` and then doing `sudo -u root` or `sudo su root` will *not* work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems not be possible through ssh. Instead of it, you should use a tty with "another" user, and follow this: https://www.howtogeek.com/116032/how-to-encrypt-your-home-folder-after-installing-ubuntu/